# Confused with Variance

Tags: scala, variance

Given the following:

```
trait Fruit

class Apple extends Fruit
class Orange extends Fruit

case class Crate[T](value:T)

def p(c:Crate[Fruit]) {  }

val cra = Crate(new Apple)
val cro = Crate(new Orange)
```

since Crate is invariant, I can't do the following (as expected):

```
scala> val fruit:Crate[Fruit] = cra
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Crate[Apple]
 required: Crate[Fruit]
       val fruit:Crate[Fruit] = cra
                                ^

scala> val fruit:Crate[Fruit] = cro
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Crate[Orange]
 required: Crate[Fruit]
       val fruit:Crate[Fruit] = cro

scala> p(cra)
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Crate[Apple]
 required: Crate[Fruit]
       p(cra)
         ^

scala> p(cro)
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Crate[Orange]
 required: Crate[Fruit]
       p(cro)
```

But why can I call method p with these when Crate is not covariant? :

```
scala> p(Crate(new Apple))
Crate(line2$object$$iw$$iw$Apple@35427e6e)

scala> p(Crate(new Orange))
Crate(line3$object$$iw$$iw$Orange@33dfeb30)
```

Have I missed some basic principles of variance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the latter cases, the compiler assumes that you want this to work and actually says

```
p(Crate( (new Apple): Fruit ))
```

which is perfectly okay.  It's the same as if you manually did

```
val f: Fruit = new Apple   // totally fine
p(Crate(f))                // Also totally fine
```

This is just a small part of the immense wizardry that the compiler applies to try to figure out what you mean with your types without making you type it all out.

Comment: Thanks. It almost seems as if the compiler is short-circuiting the invariance of Crate for method p, when it assumes the developer wants it to work. I assumed that Crate would have to be defined as Crate[+T] to have the p method work with cro, cra.

Comment: @ssanj - You're right, it does have to be defined as `+T` to work with `cro` and `cra`, which already have their types assigned.  But when you don't specify the type and generate something new, it assumes that you want something sensible if there is a sensible thing to be had.